# how to print the list in one line in python?

Tags: python

if i have this code and i need to print the output in one line how i can do that?

```
L = [('the', 'the'),('cat', 'cow'),('sat', 'sat'),('on', 'on'),('mat', 'mat'),('and', 'a'),('sleep', 'sleep')]

def getParaphrases(L):
   pre_match = 0
   mis_match = 0
   after_match = 0
   paraphrase = []
   newpar = []
   for x in L:
      if x[0] == x[1]:
         if not paraphrase == []:
            print '\n Paraphrase:', paraphrase
            paraphrase = []
         pre_match += 1
         mis_match = 0
      else:
         if pre_match >= 1:
            if mis_match == 0:
               paraphrase = []
            paraphrase.append(x)
         mis_match += 1
         if after_match >= 1:
            paraphrase.append(x)
            after_match += 1
```

the output is:

```
 Paraphrase: [('cat', 'cow')]

 Paraphrase: [('and', 'a')]
```

But, how to get the output in one line such as,

```
 Paraphrase [('cat', 'cow'), ('and', 'a') ]
```

Comment: You declare `newpar` but never use it. Append the `paraphrase` to `newpar` before resetting `paraphrase`, and print `newpar` at the end.

Comment: please can you explain what i have do?

Comment: That is exactly what I have done - Explain, instead of give you the code. Try it out. it is very simple.

Comment: You can remove a newline character from the print statement by doing something like this `print paraphrase,` the `,` will remove the newline character.

Answer (score 1):

You can replace that whole function with a list comprehension

```
L = [('the', 'the'),('cat', 'cow'),('sat', 'sat'),('on', 'on'),('mat', 'mat'),('and', 'a'),('sleep', 'sleep')]

[(i,j) for i, j in L if i != j]
```

Output

```
[('cat', 'cow'), ('and', 'a')]
```

Comment: I need the same function with out change